# apt-check / python-apt regression?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

Since beginning of February I keep seeing error messages of this kind:

```
E: Unknown Error: '<class 'KeyError'>' ("The cache has no package named 'linux-headers-5.4.0-144-generic:amd64'")
```

`apt`, `apt-cache`, `aptitude` ... none of them see a problem with the files that `apt-check` bemoans.

My problem is that we're using `apt-check` to ascertain figures of machines in need of an upgrade for both regular and security fixes.
The monitoring stays broken until I actually run an upgrade, and I can't figure out what's stuck where.

Has anyone experienced similar issues, and, better yet, managed to figure out what's going on and fix them?

Comment: I got the same problem earlier today, in the notifications panel of my Ubuntu MATE. No solution yet.

Comment: @egor83 - does your problem disappear when you run an `apt update && apt upgrade -y`?

Comment: I ran `apt update` and saw no errors related to this, but the error notification on the panel didn't go away yet. I plan to reboot soon, let's see whether it'd change anything.

Comment: Just noticed, notification is gone on its own - no reboots, or running any new commands.

Comment: You're lucky then :D ... I emergency patched our monitoring script and rolled it out to all machines via ansible about an hour after posting this ;) @egor83

Comment: @egor83 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/2007311

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found the root cause, but getting about 200 emails from cron every hour telling me that apt-check encountered a problem prompted me to find an alternative, and quickly =}

In the wrapper script that feeds the metrics to prometheus I've replaced the invocation of `apt-check` with the following:

```
/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{sec=0;up=0}/^Checking: / {if($0~/archive:[^ ]+-security/){sec++}else{up++}}END{printf "%s;%s",up+sec,sec}'
```

No, it's not pretty ... but it does the job without making whiney noises.

Answer (score 0):

Bug for this issue (backed by a customer case I filed as well for good measure):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/2007311

Inadvertent fix of issue seems to be done via:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/2008212

It's not pushed to Focal or Jammy yet but I'm pushing for that now in my customer support case since I have been playing wack a mole with this issue on a 300+ server fleet and it's no fun.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the 2nd link (the first one I had already posted in the comments above yesterday) ;) ... can't wait for it to make it out into the wild - not that I need it any longer after my work-around ;) ...